# get nft activity

Tags: web3js, blockchain, nft, react

Does anyone know how I could get the transaction logs of an nft? having the address of the collection and the token ID.

thanks guys!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use something called an **API**.
Different DApps and/or Apps have their own API's.

**Here is a list of some NFT API docs you can try:**

OpenSea API: https://docs.opensea.io/reference/api-overview

LooksRare API: https://docs.looksrare.org/developers/public-api-documentation

ICY Tools API: https://docs.icy.tools/developer-api/api-reference

You will then need to get an API key, connect to the API and use their given functions to interact with the API and get the data back :)